# How to optimally get one key and value from object consisting of one pair?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a recipeBox  App using React JS. In that App there's a state

```
this.state = {
    recipeArray: []
...}
```

User add recipes by pushing objects `{recipe_Name : Ingredients}` in that array. Afterwards I retreive key and value from object like this:
    --- to get a key

```
let key = Object.keys(this.state.recipeArray[index])
```

--- to get a value

```
const getIngredients = (obj) => {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            var ingredients = obj[property];
        }
    }
    return ingredients;
};
```

The thing is I'm getting a key and value from object with one pair {key-value}. Maybe there's a simpler way without itterating.

Comment: `getIngredients` will always return last key's value

Comment: @Rajesh: Indeed. The operating assumption, though, is that there's only one enumerable property. So last = first = only. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder question is still unclear. Object(`{recipe_Name : Ingredients}`) is pushed in array and then `key = Object.keys(this.state.recipeArray[index])`, but it will return an object. so until we know what OP wants to achieve, any answer/ suggestion would be incomplete

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear question (english is not my native) but anyway T.J.Crowder gets me right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe there's a simpler way without itterating.

Not really. You can make that iteration happen inside a provided function, though:

```
const name = Object.keys(obj)[0];
const ingredients = obj[name];
```

It's still there, it's just inside `Object.keys`.

---

That said: I'd store objects with two properties: Name and ingredients:

```
{
    name: "Pie",
    ingredients: "Lots of good stuff"
}
```

Then you could just use `obj.name` and `obj.ingredients`. Or for the code that only cares about ingredients, just `obj.ingredients`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get property using `bracket` notation:

```
for (key in obj) break;
const getIngredients=obj[key];
```

Here is a short example:

```js
var recipeArray=[];

var obj={recipe_Name : "name1"};
recipeArray.push(obj);
console.log(recipeArray);

for (key in obj) break;
const getName=obj[key];
console.log(getName);
```

Comment: `recipe_Name` would appear to be dynamic. (The question is a bit vague, granted.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I use another method to get `first` key of an `object`.

Comment: You can get property using bracket notation: - There are components in App that use and then list only ingredients without name (name is in another component). So I was getting a value without key.

Comment: I used `name` for a short example in order to explain how to get `value` from `first` key of object.

Comment: @TarasYaremkiv: *"So I was getting a value without key. "* There isn't a mechanism for doing that. The only way is to get the property's key, then use that to look up the value. If `for-of` were defined for plain objects, you could use that in ES2015, but it isn't, they didn't make plain objects iterable. You could use a `Map`, but I'd use an object with two properties as described in my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Yes, but i said that I have changed in order to not be duplicated with your answer, as you said in second comment.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you mean now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, No problem !.